# C# real name of the running process UWP

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve the real name of a UWP process, I have already tried to retrieve it through the window name `MainWindowsTitle`, `ProcessName`  and etc, I tried for windows API calls but without success, what I need is the following name:

[taskmanager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6umSn.png)

When I try to retrieve the process name by `ProcessName`  I get: Music.UI.exe if I try to recover by `MainWindowsTitle`: Grove Music if minimized and `Empty.String` if it is in any other state. I have already tried to recover by AppManifest also without success because la is not the real name of the application.

Does anyone have any solution to get the exact name as the taskmanager does with nested processes? Or at least explain how windows works with this type of application ...

Comment: Which name in the screenshot are you referring to? The top-level name of the child window or child process name?

Comment: See the **comments** in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623678/get-processes-name-like-you-can-see-in-task-manager .

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I needed.